# create multiple objects

Tags: java

Can I do something like this in the main class?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("message 1");
int nbre1 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("message 2");
int nbre2 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("message 3");
int nbre3 = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

Obj o = new Obj(nbre1, nbre2, nbre3);

// print a message "do you want to create another object?"
```

If yes, can I display messages again but don't affect variables from another object, e.g. o2?

Comment: Yes, you do something like that, obvious I'd think since you have already done it :-)

Comment: And of course it won't work because `sc`is nowhere defined.

Comment: @Dominik - It appears to be a segment of code.

Comment: I've supposed it's defined

Answer (score 0):

You can write the above code in a function and call the function in a loop.
Something like this ...

```
List<Obj> objects = new ArrayList<Obj>();
while(true){
    Obj o = new Obj();
    boolean continueBool = readInputs(o);
    objects.add(o);
    if(!continueBool){
        break;
    }
}

private boolean readInputs(Obj o){
// code to read inputs and create Obj object. If the user wants to create more objects, return TRUE else return FALSE
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("message 1");
    int nbre1 = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("message 2");
    int nbre2 = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("message 3");
    int nbre3 = sc.nextInt();
    // set values  nbre1, nbre2 and nbre3 to 'o'
    System.out.println("Do you want to repeat ?");
    String inStr = sc.nextLine();    
    if(inStr.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I change the reference every time?

Comment: `boolean continue` statement is a **disaster**. I suggest you use an IDE for coding and paste it from there directly. It'd would have shown you why its wrong.

Comment: @R.J Apologies. Corrected.